# PHP create file from string with unique name

Tags: php, file-upload

I am sending an xhr base64 encoded string from JavaScript to a php file. In php I get the content and put it in a file:

```
<?php
  $img = trim($_POST["base64"]);

  $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
  $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
  $data = base64_decode($img);
  file_put_contents('image.png', $data);

  echo 'image.png';
?>
```

How can I create a unique file name, instead of file_put_contents in image.png, set it into a /tmp folder and return the unique URL?

Thanks you.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php

Comment: I see that file_put_contents will work on a non existent file so I can use uniqid to create a filename

Comment: Do not use `uniqid`. Use `tempnam` like @Lashane mentioned it. Do check the docs before you decide to go with something that has red text screaming it doesn't produce **unique** strings.